# Losing existing Dropbox files when ownership is changed in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, integration, dropbox

When I changed the client (contact) record ownership, related Dropbox files got deleted automatically in Salesforce. The old client record owner and the new client record owner connected to the same Dropbox.